# saving database without empty string but spaces are accepting while i used @"" in sqlite in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite

i am new to cocoa sqlite in my app i am saving database in table with student data. when i am giving same name it is not accepting the name its fine, but when i giving space rather than name it accepting the spaces rather than any string. i used @"" to check if the name is empty or not , but my problem is it taking spaces..... so i want to avoid the spaces to save my data

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the NSString documentation, it appears you need to use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`, to trim the whitespace from the string before saving it. Something like this should work:

```
// Remove whitespace
NSString *trimmedString = [enteredName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet];
// Check if the string is empty
if(![trimmedString isEqualToString:@""])
{
    // Save...
}
```

Comment: +1 : the `isEqualToString` part is especially important because strings are pointers. Odds are you're doing something like `if (myString == @"")` but that will never work because even if your string is empty like that, they don't point to the same place in memory and therefor aren't equal. NSString's `isEqualToString` method compares the characters in both strings, which is what you really want.